# Implementing Achievement System in Javascript

Tags: javascript, achievements

I understand that for more complex achievements, specific code can't be avoided, but for simple ones like (player clicked 100 times) or (player earned 30 bajillion cookies) or (player played for 1 hour) it should be as simple as abstracting the achievements to something like a list of properties/values and having some event handler.

My problem is that since I'm using Javascript and there's no really clean way to do pointers, how am I supposed to create an achievement class that can be iterated through procedurally?

Ideally I'd like something like this:

**Achievement class:**

```
function Achievement(name, property, value, text, points){
  this.name = name;
  this.property = property;
  this.value = value;
  this.text = text;
}
```

And then I'd add an achievement like so:

```
achievements.push(new Achievement("Clicktastic", &numClicks, 1000, "You clicked 1000 times!");
```

And have some kind of function bound to a Window.setInterval that was constantly looping through all achievements and for these simple types doing something like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < achievements.length; i++){
  if (*achievements[i].property >= achievements[i].value){
    //deal with earning achievement
  }
}
```

I'm just using some C style pointer/dereferencing notation here.

Basic idea is that I'm not sure how to create a generic achievement that can arbitrarily care about specific properties without pointers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to implement achievement system?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/32379/best-way-to-implement-achievement-system)

Comment: I read that post thoroughly before posting this. Unfortunately I never saw a way past this pointer issue there

Comment: basically it's all well and good to store hashes of the property names. but I don't see a way to programatically map that back to the variable that property refers to

Comment: And I just don't like the way that solution has an id for each property. If you changed the order of those properties anywhere, you'd have to reflect that in a lot of code elsewhere. Unfortunately, not my kind of solution, at least aesthetically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript supports "pointers" in form of object references. All variables which contain objects actually contain pointers to objects. Further, you can access fields of objects using the `object[fieldname]` syntax. Assuming you have an object `clickManager` and want to monitor its variable `numClicks`, this would look like this:

```
achievements.push(new Achievement("Clicktastic", clickManager, "numClicks", 1000, "You clicked 1000 times!");
```

The code to check the variable monitored by an achievement would then look like this:

```
var a = achievents[i];
if (a.monitoredObject[a.monitoredVariableName] > a.value) {
```

If you want to access a global variable, you can access it over the global object "window".

But as you said, this isn't really a very beautiful solution. First, it's a bit cumbersome. Second, it's not very flexible, because all it can do is monitor numerical variables. What if you have an achievement with a more complex condition? And third, it ignores one of JavaScript's most powerful features: [Closures](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closures.shtml)!

Javascript allows you to define inline-functions which can access variables in the current scope. These inline-functions can be passed around as variables and called from somewhere else (just like function-pointers in C). To make use of this, your achievement class would look like this:

```
function Achievement(name, text, checkFunction){
  this.name = name;
  this.text = text;
  this.checkFunction = checkFunction;
}
```

An example of creating an achievement:

```
function initClickHandling() {

     var numClicks = 0;

     achievements.push(new Achievement(
           "Clicktastic", 
           "You clicked 1000 times!", 
           function() {
               return numClicks > 1000;
           })
     );


     window.onclick = function() {
          numClicks++;
     }
}
```

This unnamed function "captures" the local variable `numClicks`. When that function is executed, it will use the then-current value of `numClicks`. This even works when the function-call which declared that variable has already returned.

Also notice the second function, the click handler for `window`. It captures the same variable and manipulates it. When it does that, the check function will notice.

Your achievement management code would then look like this (using [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead of a for-loop. Another example of using ad-hoc unnamed functions):

```
 achievements.forEach(function(achievement) {
      if (achievement.checkFunction()) {
            // award the achievement
      }
 });
```

Comment: This is very nice. I like it. It's a little different from the way I wanted to do it but it solves my problem so I will implement it your way

Comment: @DavidBandel Closures are really the soul of JavaScript. The language sucks a whole lot less when you understood and mastered this feature.